# Proving $\overline{f}(x)\leq g(x)$ in Hahn-Banach Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm trying to prove the [Hahn-Banach Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem). We have $Z\subset X$. The sublinear functional on $X$ is $p$, and the linear functional on $Z$ is $f$.

In the proof, I have already found the maximal linear functional $\overline{f}$ by Zorn's lemma. Now I have to prove that the domain of $\overline{f}$ is $X$. Let us assume the domain of $\overline{f}$ is a proper subset of $X$. Then $\exists y_1\in X\setminus \mathfrak{D}(\overline{f})$ (where $\mathfrak{D}(\overline{f})$ is the domain of $\overline{f}$). We defined $g$ on the vector space generated by $\mathfrak{D}(\overline{f})$ and $y_1$ by 
$$g(y+\alpha y_1)=g(y)+\alpha c$$ Clearly $g$ is linear. Now we have to prove 
 $g(x)\leq p(x)$ for all $x\in X$.

I was wondering if the following argument works.

We know that $g(y)\leq p(y)$ for all $y\in \mathfrak{D}(\overline{f})$. Hence, $g(y+\alpha y_1-\alpha y_1)\leq p(y+\alpha y_1-\alpha y_1)$. As $p(x+y)\leq p(x)+p(y)$, we have $p(y+\alpha y_1-\alpha y_1)\leq p(y+\alpha y_1)+p(-\alpha y_1)$.

Due to the linear nature of the mapping $g$, we have $g(y+\alpha y_1)+\alpha c\leq p(y+\alpha y_1)+p(-\alpha y_1)$. Therefore, $$g(y+\alpha y_1)\leq p(y+\alpha y_1)+p(-\alpha y_1)-\alpha c$$

$y_1$ is a specific vector in $X$. Hence, $p(-\alpha y_1)$ has a specific value. If we define $p(-\alpha y_1)$ to be lower than $\alpha c$, then we're done. And in the current situation, we're free to do that.

Is my argument right? The book uses a rather contrived argument.

Thanks in advance!